# Visual Studio Code user snippets not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've enabled the default "log" snippet in VS Code. I also added another snippet. Neither show up when I type their prefixes. I have set `editor.tabCompletion` to true.

Any idea why these don't work?

Comment: Have you carefully followed these steps? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets Do they show up in Insert Snippet in the Command Palette?

Comment: No - they do not show in the Command Palette.

Comment: I've successfully added the log snippet as well.  But I have to hit tab twice.  The first clears the pop up panel, the second adds the snippet.

Comment: When I tab, it creates starting and ending HTML tags for whatever I was typing. It never recognizes my code snippets in a popup.

Comment: Wait, are you referring to the example log snippet which expands to console.log("");  ?  That only works when editing a javascript file and the snippet is saved in javascript.json.  Or are you referring to some other "log" snippet?  It sounds like you are trying to use it in an html file and that won't work. (unless possibly you create the snippet in an html.json file?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code Intellisence don't suggest snippet at first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863609/vs-code-intellisence-dont-suggest-snippet-at-first)

Comment: Also, anywhere you are using "html" for snippets/emmet, make sure to include "liquid" and "twig" if you have those enabled, to see HTML based items: `CTRL+P` `> Change Language Mode` and type `html`. I have 3 listings, it wasn't working in Html, because the default was html `liquid`.

Answer (score 96):

There are a couple of ways you can fix this problem. The problem is Intellisense is getting in the way or default putting your snippets at the bottom of the list.

First I played with the suggestion delay, but then I settled on having Intellisense put my snippets in the top of the list of suggestions with the `snippetSuggestions` user preference:

```
{
  "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
}
```

Comment: this fix my problem in Elixir.

Comment: I had to enable `other` in `editor.quickSuggestions` too.  I think I had disabled it because there was so much spam from some libraries I didn't care about.

Comment: THANK YOU!!

I switched from Atom, where my snippets always worked perfectly (could always use them, even if intellisense failed to show up). In VSC, I had issues both with intellisense not always showing up (and not being able to use my snippets when it didn't), and with my snippets not being at the top.

This was a sanity saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 71):

For react with typescript, I had to specifically add 'typescriptreact' to the scope.

```
 "scope": "javascript, typescript, typescriptreact"
```

Comment: That was it! tsx files are not recognized by "typescript" in the scope!

Comment: For jsx and tsx files, this trick solved the issue. None of the others worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue. Even in my plain JavaScript test files, which is where I was trying to use my new snippet, VS Code had the language as `javascriptreact` instead of `javascript` in the bottom right. I had to move it to a global snippet with the scope as answered, although I had to add `javascriptreact` instead as I'm not using TypeScript.

Comment: This worked for me **but** it seems that the scope property is valid only in the global snippets file. When attempting to set `"scope": "javascript, javascriptreact"` inside `javascriptreact.json` (because my snippet was not applying for files with a .js extension) VSCode would warn that *"Property scope is not allowed"*.

Answer (score 60):

Sometimes the obvious that gets overlooked first. 
Upon starting VSCode and creating a new document (Ctrl + N) it may come as a surprise that the snippets do not work.
Check in the bottom right hand corner of the VSCode editor as per default a 'Plain Text' file is presented. Change the file type to your favourite language with snippets.

This may overcome some unnecessary trouble shooting ;-)

Comment: This is exactly why my HTML emmet snippets were not working. All my user `settings.json` were totally fine, but my VSCode editor prejudged it as `Django HTML` instead. Switching it to HTML, what i needed brought the snippet functionality back.

Comment: This helped me. i was editing a html file but down the bottom right corner it identified  an html file as a "Go HTML template" file for which the regular html snippets didnt work. Worth noting above- change the file type by clicking on the "Go HTML template" text (or whatever yours is) down the bottom right hand corner

Comment: helped me in associating YAML with ansible. And now the user snippets work. Thanks!

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib, I know this is an old comment, but I just had the same issue as you. Instead of switching to HTML, you can add "django-html" to the scope of the snippet, `"scope": "javascript,html,django-html"`. In this way you can continue to use your Django extension.

Answer (score 25):

If you are trying to insert PHP snippets, its worth noting the you must manually include the

`<?php`

before the snippets will start to work.

Comment: THIS. Even though the document may be set to `PHP`, those snippets that are assigned to PHP only work when the prefix is entered within `</php ... ?>` tags. Kinda dumb TBH.

Comment: BRB ehm ehm I wanted to add a snippet that sets the opening `<?php` tag, in such a way to just type `ph` and got hinted for it. Though it doesn't work , used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220696/3446280 , I create a new PHP file and type `ph` or either `php` but it is wrong since the begin because the label is "abc" and not the square icon. The solution has been to create the snippet inside a "New global snippet file..."

Comment: If you are writing php inside html and want snippet like `<?= $0 ?>` then you need to add snippet to html.json, not php.json.

Comment: @Robert I added this snippet to plaintext.json...as long as I haven't yet saved the new file as a PHP file, it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 17):

What I actually found is that when you have a php intelliSense and you want a **php** tab tag to open and close, I added the extension to a html file type as well.

```
   {
      "Open php tag": {
         "scope": "php, html",
         "prefix": "php",
         "body": [
           "<?php",
             "  $1",
           "?>"
        ],
        "description": "Opens php tags"
      }
   }
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: super Magic stuff!

Comment: Note that this requires creating a global snippet - for obvious reasons you'll get an error when you specify extra scopes (languages) in a language-specific file.

Answer (score 13):

I had to:

1. Go to settings (Windows/Linux: **File > Preferences > Settings**, macOS: **Code > Preferences > Settings**) and type in *quick* in search box and click **Edit in settings.json**:
   [image]
2. Add

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": true
```

under the section with corresponding
file type (*markdown* in my case):

[image]

**UPDATE** It could be that you need to add this:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": "on",
    "strings": "on",
    "other": "on"
}
```

instead of just `"editor.quickSuggestions": true`, because the format might have changed since the time I wrote original answer. Check it for yourself and let me know.

Comment: tried this, but it opens as read-only. I could not find the actual file so I could open it in write. Any ideas on file location?

Answer (score 9):

1. Open a common html file.
2. look at the bottom right where the plugin is in use (example: Django HTML) and click on it
3. A window will open at the top of vscode
4. Click on "Configure file Association for.'html '..."
5. Search for "HTML" (need this in active caps lock)
6. Select the first option

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5FyH.png]
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhJ7n.png]

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was not working because I had a **space** in the name of the snippet

```
{
  ...,
  "snippet name": { // it should be snippet_name. Notice the _
    ...
  }
}
```

So make sure that:

1. You have a `{name}.code-snippets` file under `.vscode` folder
2. The name of your snippet does not contain `spaces`
3. You include your language in the scope. I had to add both `typescript` and `typescriptreact`.

Comment: I could not expect that "typescript" is not enough in React TypeScript project. So, adding "typescriptreact" put the end of my frustration about VSC snippets. Thanks!

Comment: It works in my case. I had the name: "Print to console": .... I replaced by "Print_to_console": and It works!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The extension matters when selecting scope. I had recently switched from react using .js extension to react with typescript using .tsx extension. My snippet said "javascript, typescript" so I thought I was covered, but tsx files are actually considered "typescriptreact". I changed to the following and it started working on my tsx files:

```
{   
    "Styled Component React Arrow Function With Default Export": {
    "scope": "javascript, javascriptreact, typescript, typescriptreact",
    "prefix": "scraf",
    "body": [
        "import React from 'react'",
        "import styled from 'styled-components/macro'",
        "",
        "const Container = styled.div`",
        "  display: flex;",
        "`",
        "",
        "const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} = () => {",
        "  return (",
        "    <Container>",
        "     $1",
        "    </Container>",
        "  )",
        "}",
        "export default ${TM_FILENAME_BASE}",
    ],
    "description": "Styled Component React Arrow Function With Default Export"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for overriding default snippet (log)

Overriding the log.json file snippet was not working for me in User Snippets (For Typescript at least).

**Solution:**
I created a new global snippet ( File > Preferences > User Snippets > New Global Snippets file ) with a different name 'clog' (full name: 'clog.code-snippets') and prefix and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this issue too when I created my first snippet. I added the snippet, and nothing happened.

Restarted VS Code and they started working.

Answer (score 3):

Simply **Restart VScode**. That should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The hint here is you check the full name of the language that your VSCode is automatically recognizing, so after you transform all in lowercase and remove the white spaces and add it in the scope property in the snippet file.

[image: example of vscode]

Comment: If you are using .tsx files then put `javascript,typescript,typescriptreact` in your scope settings. VSCode is showing Typescript JSX in language but adding typescriptjsx didn't work, you need `typescriptreact`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that some snippets worked, and others dont.
*(like: JavaScript Snippets worked well)*

My issue solved when i installed a plugin that added the respective, specific **filetype association** (im my case: *.blade.php)

When creating UserSnippets at blade.json it worked fine.

1. Check your file extension and look if there's a plug-in suited for your file type.
2. Install and try adding the snippet again.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to specify the language in global snippet. In my case it fixed.

```
{
  "Print to console": {
        "scope": "javascript,vuex,vue",
        "prefix": "debes",
        "body": [
            "// eslint-disable-next-line",
            "debugger;"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing `"editor.tabCompletion": true` to `"editor.tabCompletion":"on"` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For any other morons out there like me...

I had a `typescript` file I was using with react, so you need `typescriptreact` listed in your snippet.

But I was also naming my file with a `.jsx` extension instead of a `.tsx` extension which is why it wasn't showing up...

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me,  i was settings `typescriptjsx` but it didn't work, settings `typescriptreact` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to setup a snippet to auto add the php open and close tags into my file, as [Robert Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119011/7311767) noted it only worked when I was already writing inside the code specific type block.

So I set `!p` to load `<?php$1?>` whenever I use it inside an HTML block. The snippet was set into the html.json file.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue, I was working with react native and my JavaScript snippets weren't working. I checked settings.json by going to settings, searched for quick suggestions, and then edit in settings.json.

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact" // This needed changed to "javascript".
  }
```

Otherwise, you can create the snippets for javascriptreact.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your file is JavaScript, not json.
// You should save your snippets in javascript.json instead of json.json.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if anyone made the same "just messing around" mistake that I did, but the profiles(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) functionality almost did me in. I had selected a different profile from my default and everything changed. Extensions, snippets, keyboard shortcuts, and probably more I didn't notice. This is just after I was telling everyone how awesome the settings sync is. I had managed to change my profile via the gear in the bottom of the main side bar. The moment I changed back to default everything came back.

[image]

Comment: To be clear: You are saying that code snippets are specific to a VS Code profile?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I couldn't point to a specific piece of documentation but when I switched they weren't working and the moment I switched the profile they came back so that is the impression I have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this, be sure to also check the scope defined within the snippet. Snippets weren't showing up for me although the file type matches, and removing the languages from the scoped solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is that another language is active in VS Code. Check the lower left hand corner of
VS Code to change the language to the desired one. Screenshots below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfyci.png)

Click on C++ then an input box will appear at the top. Type in the appropriate language, for example HTML and the issue will resolve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt0u5.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio Code How to add the `<?php` opening tag snippet**

Just for the sake of preventing some headache to those who wants to add the handy `<?php` opening tag snippet

If you follow the instructions on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets you'll got misled since you are hinted to find the wanted language in File>Preferences>User Snippets

so you type PHP and you'll edit `php.json`

... but this won't work, because the mechanism works ONLY AFTER the VSCode editor knows this is a PHP file and the filter at bottom right corner looks will not consider itself until you don't add a `<?php` at the begin of the file

no way

despite filename extension

despite you even manually set the "Select language mode" to PHP (though with PHP extension in the filename, this will be already set to PHP mode)

The unique solution I have found is to add the snippet to a "New global snippet file..."

you will find this option as first as soon you browse to
File>Preferences>User Snippets

This solution is obvious ... but only after that you guess it :-) since you add this global,

in fact the snippet in global, as it suggests, will work "globally, in any type of file type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My best strategy is to save my snippets as "Global Snippets" ( .code-snippets" format) whenever I am working on a big project and that way I never have any problem at all.. they always show up.. your global snippets are located on the same file with your ".json" snippets..

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with my react project in VSCode then I edited the settings.json. Basically, I added the below lines to the settings.json file.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone had the audacity to commit in the project that I shouldn't use snippets:

```
// .vscode/settings.json
{
  "[go]": {
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
  },
}
```

I removed that line and my user settings kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to add snippets to .jsx and .tsx

Go Code/Gear > Preferences > User Snippers

For .tsx type typescriptreact.json
For .jsx type javascriptreact.json

Add your snippets there.

````
  {"Example": {
    "prefix": "$example",
    "body": [
      " {",
      "type: example,",
      "},"
    ],
    "description": "Example"
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following configuration value set to `false`, which effectively disabled all snippet suggestions via IntelliSense. Switch the setting to `true` to enable them again.

```json
{
  "editor.suggest.showSnippets": true
}
```

As others have mentioned, you can also configure where snippets should appear in your IntelliSense suggestion list by setting the property `"editor.snippetSuggestions"` to either `top`, `bottom`, `inline` or `none`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check your code to ensure that there no errors  shown, I had included to snippet objects like shown, make sure its only one snippet Object,cannot be 2 of them. U first snippet will work, the second one will have an error, u might include another one by mistake while copy pasting

```
    {snippets object
}


    {snippets object
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Install CodeLLDB platform package from vscode extension market. It should be fix your problem