# My react intellisense doesn't work when react run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-router, code-snippets

My react snippets don't work when I run react. For example, when I press `control+space`,there is **loading...** instead of snippets.

I removed my vs code & all of its snippets then install them again for solving problem but it doesn't work.
Unfortunately, I still have problem ,
do you have any idea about my problem. What could I do to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Could you try this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321000/visual-studio-code-user-snippets-not-working/46574024

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice extension for writing `react` and `redux` codes on `vs Code`, Go to your `extensions` in `vsCode` then search and install `ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets` . Cheers! you are good to go.

Comment: Doesnt work well for me.trigger on every third attempt(OS Ubuntu 18.04 && VSC).