# how to make user snippets work inside strings: vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've made own user snippet code for javascript

```
"inner backquote concat variable" : {
    "prefix": "$",
    "body": "\\${$1}",
    "description": "concat variable with backquote sting"
}
```

I want that snippet to work inside backquote string or single quote string when I press '$' like this

[image: snippetwork.gif]

but it does not work when inside a string.

[image: heloquote.gif]

How do make the snippet work inside a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following snippet in settings.json

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    },
```

It makes all snippets/emmets working on strings.

Answer (score 2):

Together with @Ridwan's suggestion your example still wouldn't work because you have no space between `$` and the `backtick` - so vscode does not see the `$` as your prefix, it is just part of a larger string and so doesn't look like a unique trigger it is expecting.

You can see this with any snippet in or out of a string (using your snippet):

[image: snippet prefix demo]

So the snippet prefix must "stand alone" so to speak so it can be recognized as a separate trigger.  And that includes not being next to a `"` or `backtick`.  They must have spaces around them.